# How to compare currentUser with entry.author?

Tags: author, current-user

How can I compare the results of currentUser and entry.author on an entry page?
I've tried the following, but none of these get a positive result:

```
{% if  currentUser == 'entry.author.id' %}
```

Or

```
{% set author %}{{ entry.author.id }}{% endset %}
{{ author }}
{% if currentUser.id == '{{ author }}' %}
```

(I'm aiming to provide a way for the author of an entry to be presented with a form to edit the entry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% if currentUser.id == entry.author.id %}
```

When using quotation marks, it means that it's a string in Twig. What you want to do is compare the value of the actual variable.

Also, `currentUser` is a UserModel, so you need to get the id property to compare it with `entry.author.id`.

Comment: Yes, that works although I'm sure I tried it!